# Different Domains with URL Re-Writes

Tags: url, htaccess, rewrite, domain

I have several areas of my website which content authors want they content to be available at their own domain name for identity and advertising reasons. I want to avoid setting up additional multisites as most of these are very small subsections of the much larger parent  site.

For example, the current url for a subsection wanting their own domain would look like this...

http://domain.com/section/subsection/category/thisismysite

the content users want to be able to access the site at

http://thisismysite.com

The major issues come when I want to keep the url short for additional subpages within the "thisismysite" sub section, say...

http://thisismysite.com/about 
would be the same as 
http://domain.com/section/subsection/category/thisismysite/about

Any ideas on how i can accomplish this for my users?

Answer (score 1):

few months ago I had similar work to do, I had tried many (many) solutions and rewrite hacks but I'm not a htaccess guru and I was almost ready to drop it, but then I remembered I can park domains on my package and once domain is directed to your site, you can do with it something.

So, what I have in my htaccess rules for removing index.php and later I have few lines that handle new domain request. You must have that other domain for testing, besides that iys hard to know if will work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Classic index.php remove
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#get request from new domain and rewrite destination
#maybe you can do something different, but this worked for me
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?thisismysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /section/subsection/category/thisismysite/$1 [L]
```

If this doesn't work for you (even I had almost exact requirements as you), maybe you can play around this solution.

Comment: This is close, I will continue to play with it and see if I can get a solution, thanks for posting.

Comment: Ok, I hope it helps you get it to what you need.

Comment: Di you found a solution to your problem @MikeMcBrien ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and somebody had a solution for me. I think it will be useful for you too. This **free** add-on is called [Freeway](https://github.com/averyvery/freeway). Then you can just map up the desired URL with the actual URL like this:

> section/subsection/category/thisismysite/{{entry}} => {{entry}}

Then people will be able to visit `/about` and EE will treat it as if they visited section/subsection/category/thisismysite/about and use the appropriate template_group/template.

Comment: Will this work with multiple domains?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This add-on supports no MSM (Multi Site Manager).

Comment: Well that kinda takes that out of the mix for me - thanks for the info.

Comment: I am sorry. This was the only solution I knew that might help. On the other side, take a look at the ExpressionEngine [Community Forums](http://ellislab.com/forums) to see if somebody had the same issue and might have a solution. Or look at possible better add-ons at [Devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/) that are compatible with multi domains. Or await another solution here at this topic on this forum.